# Correctly setup an LMM for statistical analysis

Tags: statistics

For a statistical analysis of a medical treatment I want to use an LMM (linear mixed model) and am quite unsure on how to do that correctly (in particular how to apply it to the program SPSS, which I want to use). For simplicity I renamed every parameter to an intelligible example which conveys the same problem (but doesn't expect anyone to know medical terminology).

I have around 50 schools, each of which have between 5 and 50 students who took the course. Previous analysis' have already found the test to be effective, so while potentially interesting (meaning: I'd take the result of effectiveness of the course, if it were easy to analyse) I am not trying to figure out whether or not this course actually improves the students' ability to do maths. Instead, I want to group the students (those from the language focussed classes, those from history and geography and those from sports classes) and test, whether the crash course improvement of students' abilities is statistically significantly greater for any of the three groups. The naive approach is to simply compare one group's results before, during and after the crash course (three tests at different points in time where my data is just the result of the test for every student that took it) to a different group's results in a t-test or an ANOVA. These results entirely disregard the dependencies of students from the same school though, who might have had the same teachers or the same overall focus. Also, the repeated measurements for the same students will skew the results.

My research brought me to a Linear Mixed Model, which is supposed to be the correct concept for such a test. Since I didn't take a statistics class, I am very much unsure how to setup the model correctly. In particular, which of my parameters (time, group, student, school) is a factor, which a covariat, how do I make sure that different students from the same school are not considered independent from one another, and how to I implement the model in SPSS? The documentation on SPSS's LMM is laughably bad, but it is the only program I have access to.